# Challenging token error

Tags: java, class, postgresql, arduino, processing

I improved the structure after a good observation from [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1690199/v-k] I am still getting a token error even though the syntax looks correct to me. More comments and critiques will be useful and acknowledged here.

```
import de.bezier.data.sql.*; 

PostgreSQL pgsql;
Float val;

void setup()
{
    size( 100, 100 );
    println(val);
}
```

Token error identified in Processing 2 at Class Database.

```
Class Database 
{
    String user     = "user";
    String pass     = "pass";
    String database = "db";
    Float val;

    Database (Float col) {
      val = col;
    }

    void database_connection( col ) 
    {
      //sets up database
      pgsql = new PostgreSQL( this, "127.0.0.1", database, user, pass );

        if ( pgsql.connect() )
        {
          pgsql.query( "SELECT col FROM table ORDER BY col DESC LIMIT 1; " );
          return( pgsql.getFloat("col") );
        }
        else
        {
          println ("failed to connect to the database");
        }
      }
}
```

OLD ISSUE: Class structure addressed after a great observation from [http://stackoverflow.com/users/1690199/v-k]

import de.bezier.data.sql.*; 
.....
.....
Old code removed for clarity of this issue.

Comment: Don't use a capital in 'class' keyword. The convention is capital only in class name 'DataBase'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes don't take arguments. Also it is class not Class... Am i missing something?  Look, a general sample:

```
class Database {
  String user = "user";
  String pass = "pass";
  String database = "db";
  float val; //by convention no Caps for vars...

  // a constructor, which get partameters
  Database (float v) {
    val = v;
  }

  // a method 
  void database_setup() {
    //whateverq
  }
}//end of Database class
```

Comment: I am a new programmer overall.  :-) +1 +1 +1 This was a step in the right direction I think.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should create a new question if you have a second question. Second, you never create the variable `pgsql`, you just start using it immediately. Move this line:

```
 PostgreSQL pgsql;
```

to this group of lines:

```
String user     = "user";
String pass     = "pass";
String database = "db";
float val;
```

It's a variable that gets used in that class, so put it in that class. Also, use "float" with a lowercase "f" :)